# How to create multiple app in single angular cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using `ng generate application demo1` command in my angular cli project, where I am getting `Invalid blueprint: application` error on my console.

This is on a Linux machine with @angular/cli: 1.2.7 ,node v8.0.0, I've generated new cli project using ng new my-app command, then tried  `ng generate application demo1` command.

I expect two app folders i.e app & demo1 in in src directory but got `Invalid blueprint: application` error.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDNqh.png)

Answer (score 1):

You current CLI version `1.2.7` is quite old and does not support `application` flag.
Updating to the latest Angular CLI version 7 will fix it.

Please check these links:

1. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki#angular-cli
   Pay attention to the **Note** on this page for the updated .
2. https://angular.io/cli

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded version to "@angular/cli": "^7.3.8". now shows Cannot find module 'readable-stream' error after command ng generate application demo1

Comment: Error:Cannotfindmodule'readable-stream'atFunction.Module._resolveFilename(module.js:485:15)atFunction.Module._load(module.js:437:25)atModule.require(module.js:513:17)atrequire(internal/module.js:11:18)atObject.<anonymous>(/home/ashwini/BACKUP/2App/my-app/node_modules/duplexify/index.js:1:76)atModule._compile(module.js:569:30)atObject.Module._extensions..js(module.js:580:10)atModule.load(module.js:503:32)attryModuleLoad(module.js:466:12)atFunction.Module._load(module.js:458:3)atModule.require(module.js:513:17)atrequire(internal/module.js:11:18)atObject.<anonymous>(/home/ashwini/BACKUP/2App/my-

Comment: I could't able to post all error because character limitation

Comment: My package.json
  "@angular/cli": "^7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",

Comment: It's strange that even after updating the cli, your `@angular/compiler` version is still showing `4.0.0`. This could be causing the issue. Can you please try creating a fresh project in a new directory. The CLI should create one with latest Angular version i.e. 7

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your angular cli application.

go for [nrwl](https://nrwl.io/) to build multiple apps or use [angular schematics](https://blog.angular.io/schematics-an-introduction-dc1dfbc2a2b2) to build and maintain multiple apps.